# Unexpected behavior from lexer and grammar for simple calculator

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I'm starting on the whole world of Flex and Bison. So I followed a tutorial to write this l file for flex:

```
%{
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   void yyerror(char *);
   #include "y.tab.h"
%}

%%

 /******************** RULES ********************/

 /* One letter variables */
[a-z]         {
         yylval = *yytext - 'a'; // This is to return a number between 0 and 26 representting the letter variable.
         printf("VAR: %s\n",yytext);
         return VARIABLE;
              }

 /* Integer constants */
[0-9]+        {
         yylval = atoi(yytext);
         printf("INT: %d\n",yylval);
         return INTEGER;
              }

 /* Operators */
[-+()=/*\n]+  { printf("OPR: %s\n",yytext); return *yytext; /*\n is considered an operator because it signals the end of a statement*/ }

 /* This skips white space and tab chararcters */
[ \t]         ;


 /* Anything esle is not allowed */
.             yyerror("Invalid character found");

 /***************** SUBROUTINES *****************/
%%

int yywrap(void){
   return 1;
}
```

And this is the grammar:

```
/***************** DEFINITIONS *****************/

%token INTEGER VARIABLE
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'

%{
   void yyerror(char *);
   int yylex(void);
   int sym[26];
%}

%%
/******************** RULES ********************/

program:
        program statement '\n'
        |
        ;

statement:
        expr                        { printf("EXPR: %d\n", $1); }
        | VARIABLE '=' expr         { sym[$1] = $3; }
        ;
expr:
        INTEGER
        | VARIABLE                  { $$ = sym[$1]; }
        | expr '+' expr             { $$ = $1 + $3; }
        | expr '-' expr             { $$ = $1 - $3; }
        | expr '*' expr             { $$ = $1 * $3; }
        | expr '/' expr             { $$ = $1 / $3; }
        | '(' expr ')'              { $$ = $2; }
        ;
%%
/***************** SUBROUTINES *****************/
void yyerror(char *s){
   printf("%s\n",s);
}

int main(void) {
   yyparse();
   return 0;
}
```

And serveral question arise. The first comes when compiling. This is how I compile:

```
bison -d bas.y -o y.tab.c
flex bas.l
gcc y.tab.h lex.yy.c  y.tab.c -o bas_fe
```

Which gives me two warnings like this:

```
bas.y:24:7: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
         expr                        { printf("EXPR: %d\n", $1); }
       ^
bas.y: In function ‘yyerror’:
bas.y:39:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
    printf("%s\n",s);
```

Now, they are warnings and the print work, but I found it odd, since I have clearly included the libraries for use of the printf function.

My real question arises from my interaction with the program. This is the console output:

```
x = (3+5)
VAR: x
OPR: =
OPR: (
INT: 3
OPR: +
INT: 5
x
OPR: )

VAR: x
syntax error
```

Several questions arise from this.
1) Upon inputting x = (3+5) the program printout does not include the ')' Why?

2) When inputting x (expected output would have been 8) only then the ')' appears. Why?

3) And then there is the "syntax error" message. I'm assuming the message is automatically generated within the code of y.tab.c. Can it be changed to somthing more meaningful? Am I right in assuming that the syntax error is because the program found ) and newline and the variable and that this DOES NOT correspond to a program statement, as defined by the grammar?

Comment: In the whitespace you indeed may want to add `\n`: `[ \t\n]`. The syntax error detected is from the `\n` on the input line. For the compiler warning on printf: are the lexer and parser in the same file? I also note that the lexical rule `[-+()=` doesn't terminate properly; it should terminate (after removing the comments) with `]` but ends with `}`.

Comment: Yes. It seems that the problem is solved by adding an space after the ) in the input. I tried what you said and the syntax erro went away. The lexical rule is fine. My editor colors it correctly, it seems here it doesn't, I don't know why. Also the lexer and parser are not in the same file. You can look. at the commands I use for compiling.

Comment: Make sure you `#include <stdio.h>` in the parser to make the `printf` warning go away.

Comment: The lexical rule is not ok. Check manually; maybe your editor gets a problem on the embedded `/*`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Aside from being way too long for human readers, there is nothing syntactically wrong with that lexical rule.

Comment: the rule, after removing the comments, degrades to `[-+()= } [ \t] ;` But I am happy if you are happy.

Comment: @paulogilvie: the `/*` inside the *pattern* does not start a comment. Comments are only recognized in actions (or on lines by themselves which start with whitespace). See the flex manual.

Comment: @rici, Ah! You got me there! So the rule is `[-+()=/*\n]+`. Didn't see that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> #### I have clearly included the libraries for use of the printf function.
>
> You included `stdio.h` in your flex file, but not in your bison file. And the warnings about `printf` being undeclared are from your bison file, not your flex file.

When you compile multiple files with gcc (or any other C compiler), the files are compiled independently and then linked together. So your command

```
gcc y.tab.h lex.yy.c  y.tab.c -o bas_fe
```

does not concatenate the three files and compile them as a single unit. Rather, it compiles the three files independently, including uselessly compiling the header file `y.tab.h`.

What you should do is add a prolog block including `#include <stdio.h>` to your `bas.y` file.

#### `[-+()=/*\n]+   {... return *yytext; ...}`

This flex pattern matches *any number* of characters from the set `[-+()=/*\n]`. So in the input `x=(3+5)\n`, the `)\n` is being matched as a *single token*. However, the action returns `*yytext`, the first character of `yytext`, effectively ignoring the `\n`. Since your grammar requires `\n`, that creates a syntax error.

Simply remove the repetition operator from the pattern.

#### Can the error message be changed to something more meaningful?

If you have a reasonably modern bison, add the declaration

```
%error-verbose
```

to the beginning of your bison file.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have fixed the file as you said and effectively solved all of my problems. I appreciate it a lot. Although one thing you say the patter matches ANY NUMBER: I think it matches one ore more of the characters in that set, right?

Comment: @aarelovich. Correct. Any number at least one. But no flex pattern other than <<EOF>> matches zero characters, even if the regex would.